# Is it more efficient to separate code that doesn't need to be run as often from the main game loop in another loop in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, performance

I'm creating my first Javascript game, and I want the game to continuously make a check for something as the game goes on. The check is somewhat costly, and the main game loop runs every 25 miliseconds, so I'd rather it not be in the game loop. I was thinking about separating that check in a function that will be called by a setInterval() every second. I would think this would make my code more efficient, right?

This is what the main loop looks like:

```
var gameLoop = new CustomEvent("gameLoop")
function main() {
    document.dispatchEvent(gameLoop)
}
setInterval(main, 25)
```

So basically, I could either do this:

```
function check() {
      //Check code here
    }
}
setInterval(check, 1000)
```

Or:

````
document.addEventListener("gameLoop", function() {
    //check code here
})```
````

Comment: Why is the check not important enough to run at every tick? Would you be fine with not running the check at all?

Comment: Basically I have "debris" that continuously get created at the top of the screen, and they continually fall. The check is to determine when a certain debris piece falls outside of the viewport. Once that happens, I want to delete the element. It doesn't need to be run EXACTLY when the element falls out of the viewport though.

Comment: Why do you consider that check "somewhat costly"? You probably have to look at each debris object anyway on each tick to update their positions.

Comment: Yeah, you're right, I guess I had a brain fog moment, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is a clean way to separate the high frequency events from the low frequency events.

To mix in other intervals like 50 ms or 75 ms you can also add a global variable like `tick_count_25` and use the mod operator in the 25 ms function.

outside of function

```
var tick_count_25 = 0;
```

inside of function

```
tick_count_25++;
....
if ((tick_count_25 % 3) == 0)  // every 75 ms
{
      ... some function that only needs to run once every 3 ticks
}
```

That lets you avoid creating 20 interrupts and keeps your game loop logic in 1-2 places instead of many.

It also lets you set delayed triggers, say if you want something to happen 20 ticks from now, though you can also do that by adding more global counters that persist outside of the interrupt.